# Mongodb Query Returns No Results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I am running the following mongodb query.  It returns no results.  Please correct me where I went wrong.
**QUERY**

```
mongoexport -d crawler-db -c person -f photo,crawledUrl -q "{'crawledDate':{'$lte': new Date(1399939200)}}" -o per1305.csv
```

**RESULT**

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
exported 0 records
```

I expect some results.

Comment: How many records do you get when you run find() for the same query?

Comment: > 3.4 Lakhs record It returns.

Comment: Please provide comments when voting down an answer. Sure helps